# iMacros task: possible or not?

Tags: imacros

I would like to create a macro for adding a filter to Yahoo email addresses. At this stage all I want to know is if it's possible or not. It seems to me the problem is getting into the settings screen. To do that you have to hover over an icon and select from a drop down menu.